# C# EF Core DataBase-First как создать первую и последующие миграций?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Я создаю слепок БД с помощью команды Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Test;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables Chin, Roles -OutputDir Models\DistrictUsers -Context UsersContext
Создаются классы на основе имеющейся БД.

```
 public partial class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Chin> Chin { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее хочу добавить столбец TestProperty в таблицу Roles

```
public partial class Roles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public int TestProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Далее вызываю команду в Консоле деспетчера пакетов Add-migration InitializeMigration 
При выполнении команды получается что создается скрипт, который формирует создание двух таблиц Roles,  Chin, Но они то в БД уже есть. А я хотел чтобы добавилось только новое свойство TestProperty. А при запуске update-DataBase получается запустится скрипт по созданию двух таблиц.... 
Зачем тогда делается слепок таблиц с помощью команды Scaffold-DbContext?

Подскажите что я не так делаю? Как правильно сделать слепок существующей БД и потом изменять Таблицы в БД с помощью миграции?

Comment: Спасибо. Определился.EF Core

Comment: У вас Database-first, какие миграции? Миграции - это для Code First, для Database-First - пилите БД руками или своими какими то скриптами, миграции не предназначены для Database-first

Comment: У меня Legacy проект. Взаимодействие через Адо. Странно конечно. Тем способом что я ниже написал не получится дальше взаимодействие с БД и постепенное управление и изменение базы данных? Code first идёт от классов . Так при database first классы таким способом тоже появляются сформированные студией. Толку просто тогда от ef если вы говорите пилите руками. Смысл ведь ef абстрагироваться от ручных скриптов. Разве нет?

Comment: Entity Framework - это ORM, ORM - это про маппинг, а не про миграции. Вы берете какую то побочную функциональность библиотеки, которая в принципе присутствует как часть для конкретного подхода code first и пытаетесь использовать его не по назначению, вот у вас и не получается.

Comment: На ваш взгляд то что я пытаюсь сделать, даст мне возможность полностью перейти на взаимодействие с БД через ef? По сути у меня такая идея есть готовая БД и возможность написать mvc приложение. Но так как БД уже есть code first не подходит. Но я не хочу через Адо взаимодействие осуществлять. Просто нет опыта с ef вот и нет идей как с помощью database first работать. Если не Hello word....

Comment: в вашем случае взаимодействие с EF сведется к тому, что вы по готовой БД сгенерируете контекст и сможете использовать контекст для отправки запросов в БД. Работа же со схемой БД уже вне ответственности EF при подходе database-first

Comment: Как я понял, БД уже есть и поэтому вы по ней сгенерировали контекст и сущности - Database First. А далее хотите использовать CodeFirst. Ну, правильно сделали: в самой первой миграции ручками удалили ненужное, а дальше миграции будут работать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо ответ. Завтра буду пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Сделал первую миграцию. Пустой

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
```

Далее в Классе Role добавил свойство TestProperty . 
Сделал Миграцию 
add-Migration v2. 
обновил БД
update-database